# Android - set layout width dynamically for buttons

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I automated the process of creating the layout and the buttons it contains. Working with the GUI that Eclipse provide for editing layout, it let the use set the button's layout width property. I wish to do the same through code (dynamically). Basically, I wish to set the button's layout width property to MATCH_PARENT.

A snipped code or a good reference will be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your container is a LinearLayout its going to be like this:

```
    LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

    Button btn = new Button(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
      LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    btn.setLayoutParams(lp);

    container.addView(btn);
```

Comment: thank your for your reply. i am using table layout, and it seems that the table layout cannot be manipulated in the same manner.

Comment: If you use tablelayout, youre Buttons width will be influences by the layout attributes [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html#attr_android:stretchColumns)